# Google Chrome disappeared entirely

Tags: kubuntu, google-chrome

Google Chrome suddenly disappeared from my computer entirely after a reboot. I was using Chromium for some time but suddenly, Chrome appeared without me downloading it, and I thought something weird with the updates happened. So I was using it for some months and today it is just gone. I only care for my bookmarks. Is there anything I can do to restore it? or any thoughts on why this thing happened? (I am using Kubuntu 12.04 on a Dell Latitude E5420)

Comment: You must have done *something*. The Google Chrome browser is not even in the official Ubuntu repositories, only chromium is.

Comment: You probably added the Google Chrome PPA.

Comment: Did chrome reappear? I booted up my system this morning and chrome was gone... but reappeared 20 minutes later. Chrome is a "snap" and they update themselves. I think that chrome update took a long time this morning for some unknown reason.

Answer (score 0):

All of Chromium's data should be stored in `/home/username/.config/chromium`. To be more precise, your bookmarks are located in

`/home/username/.config/chromium/<Profile ##>/Bookmarks`

or

`/home/username/.config/chromium/Default/Bookmarks`.

If the bookmarks are really important, save a backup of this file. Then you can reinstall the `chromium-browser` package and it should hopefully find the bookmarks.

Comment: I only found a txt file called Bookmarks. Is there an actual html file there or not?

Comment: @nebula It looks like json, open it in a text editor and you'll see. I assume you could even import it to other browsers directly.

Comment: I found a .txt and a .bak file. Which one of the 2 do you mean? Also i cannot import any of them since when Chromium is searching for a file to import bookmarks it searches only for HTML files

Comment: @nebula The file I'm referring to is simply called `Bookmarks` without extension. And Chromium is loading its configuration from the folder I mentioned, so if it exists, it will be loaded by Chromium. I'm not talking about automatic import. And I suggested to backup the `Bookmarks` in case it would get overwritten or something.